# Redirect to a folder containing pdf files on dropdown list selected item using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a folder under "solution" in my visual studios which contains pdf files.
I have a dropdown list and on selecting a specific value, I want one of the pdf to be downloaded based on what dropdown item user have selected.
Can anyone guide me how to do this. I am new to coding and any help is appreciated.
Thanks. 
Here is my .aspx page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphforContentOne" runat="server">
<div class="input-group input-group-primary">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="SalesProjections" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SalesProjections_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Choose a year to download" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2018" Value="2018"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2017" Value="2017"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2016" Value="2016"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2015" Value="2015"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2014" Value="2014"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
Protected Sub SalesProjections_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Select Case SalesProjections.SelectedIndex
            Case 2018

            Case 2017

            Case 2016

            Case 2015

            Case 2014

        End Select
    End Sub
```

I dont know how to link that pdf file in folder here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Protected Sub SalesProjections_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    dim FilePath as string="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\app1\pdfs" & SalesProjections.SelectedValue & ".pdf"
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & SalesProjections.SelectedValue & ".pdf")
    Response.TransmitFile(FilePath)
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

just FYI it looks like you want to use selectedvalue and not selectedindex

Comment: This works and yes I had to change it to SelectedValue. Thanks :)